# How to automate Google Classroom posting at student enrollment

Tags: google-classroom

How to automate Google Classroom docs, assignments, posts, etc.. to be delivered to a student after enrollment, at a precise frequency, in relation to the date of enrollment

I mean a kind of onboarding:

- Day 0 from enrollment: publish classwork for subject x
- Day 5 from enrollment: ask for an assignment
- Day 10 from enrollment: publish classwork for subject y
- ... and so on.

Comment: Currently there is no direct way to do it through the Google Classroom interface, the only workaround I could think of is to use Apps Script but for this option to work, you would have to create one classroom per student because when you create an assignment this is created for the class not per student.